# Creating property for an object during run time

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I am trying to create a property for an object like shown below but if I type Object.keys(window.data) I am getting the object name as **DENTAL[object Object]**

**Method goes like this:**

```
function GetAppliedFilterValue(TabName, filter) { //TabName="DENTAL", filter.CoverageId = 10
    var property = TabName.concat(String(filter.CoverageId)); 
    window.data[property.toString()] = {};
```

Where am I going wrong?

PS. the coverageId property of object filter is **Number** type

Comment: try using .toString() in concat also. Smthing like 
`var property = TabName.concat(filter.CoverageId.toString()); ` I doubt using String() as you have done

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari Nope.. .toString() didn't work

Comment: This syntax of creating object key takes string like window.data["property"]. 

Can you try consoling property variable to see what exactly is it....Also try typeof to determine its type... it should be a string.

Comment: "*the coverageId property of object filter is Number type*" - well, no, a number wouldn't yield `[object Object]`.

Comment: `TabName` is a string, right? There's no reason to use `concat` then or even `property.toString()`. Just `window.data[TabName + String(filter.CoverageId)]` should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Bergi, your suggestion helped me that worked.

**My implementation:**

```
function GetAppliedFilterValue(TabName, filter) {
    var property = TabName + String(filter.CoverageId);
    window.data[property.toString()] = {};
```